# Moment Generating Function of the Product of Three I.I.D Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, moment-generating-functions, binomial-distribution

Let X1, X2, X3 be i.i.d. random variables with distribution
$P(X_1 =0)=\frac13, P(X_1 =1)= \frac {2}{3}$
Calculate the moment generating function of $Y = X_1X_2X_3.$

My work:

$M_x(t)= E(e^{tx}) = \sum e^{tx} p(x) = (1-p) + e^{t}p = \frac {1}{3} + \frac{2e^t}{3}$

My question is this statement true? $M_y(t)= \sum e^{tx_1x_2x_3}p_{x_1}(x)p_{x_2}(x)p_{x_3}(x) \ne [M_x(t)]^3$

*change made in above equation to correspond with given answer [not equal] added*

Comment: First try to derive $M_Y(t)$. What values can $Y$ take? With what probabilities do these values occur? If you can answer these two questions, can you derive $M_Y(t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment generating function is given by
$$
M_Y(t)=\operatorname Ee^{tY}=(1-(2/3)^3)e^{t\cdot0}+(2/3)^3e^{t\cdot 1}=1-(2/3)^3+(2/3)^3e^t
$$
and it is not equal to $M_{X_1}^3(t)$.

Comment: Okay I see. i will modify the post to show change. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing to do is to observe that the product $Y = X_1 X_2 X_3$ is itself Bernoulli, and that the probability that $Y = 1$ is equal to the probability that **each** of $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ is equal to $1$, since that is the only way that the product is $1$.

Comment: Very true! Thank you.